# How to attach document (image or etc.) to existing work item Azure DevOps using Java or curl utility

Tags: java, azure, curl, azure-devops

How to attach document (image or etc.) to existing work item Azure DevOps using Java or curl utility. I tried to do it with curl utility and java code, and it doesn't work. The example of java code:

```
 try {
        // urlOfAttachment - url of attachment to devops azure, got with this method: 
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62034062/upload-an-attachment-to-azure-devops-rest-api
        String jsonInputString = "[{\"op\":\"add\",\"path\":\"/relations/-\",\"value\":" +
                "{\"rel\":\"HelloFile.txt\",\"url\":\"" + urlOfAttachment + "\"," +
                "\"attributes\":{\"comment\":\"Spec for the work\"}}}]";

        URL url = new URL(
                "https://dev.azure.com/[organization]/[project]/_apis/wit" +
                        "/workItems/2?api-version=5.1");
        // PAT - token
        HttpURLConnection con = apiConnectionAttachToTicket(PAT, url, jsonInputString);

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String responseLine = null;
            while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(responseLine.trim());
            }
            System.out.println("There would be response");
            System.out.println(response.toString());
            System.out.println("End of response");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        con.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public static HttpURLConnection apiConnectionAttachToTicket(String PAT, URL url, String jsonInputString) {
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    try {
        String AuthStr = ":" + PAT;
        Base64 base64 = new Base64();

        String encodedPAT = new String(base64.encode(AuthStr.getBytes()));
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedPAT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json-patch+json");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        System.out.println("URL - " + url.toString());
        System.out.println("PAT - " + encodedPAT);

        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH");
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("data", jsonInputString);
        System.out.println("Exit from function");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return con;
}
```

This method returns 411 error. I think because it doesn't set method type as PATCH, but uses POST. But POST isn't supported by DevOps Azure (I got it when tried to use curl). When I use curl, it returns message: "You must pass a valid document in the body of the request". But I checked it several times, and it seems right. The example of curl request:

```
curl -L -D- --user [mail]@gmail.com:[token] --header "Content-Type:application/json-patch+json" --request POST -d '{"op":"add","path":"/relations/-","value":"AttachedFile","url":"https://dev.azure.com/[orgranization]/280b4f85-e666-4069-8b3b-2116ff5d9b7a/_apis/wit/attachments/ff9f26e7-6595-462d-833c-40f9771f3035?fileName=HelloFile.txt","attributes":{"comment":"Spec for the work"}}}' https://dev.azure.com/[organization]/[project]/_apis/wit/workitems/2?api-version=6.0
```

Maybe any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could first try to use **Postman** to test your JSON format. Check if you could use REST API with that json body to upload attachments.

If a *comment* isn't specified, it doesn't link correctly. i.e. This code:

Should have been:

```
json=[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value": {
            "rel": "AttachedFile",
            "url": attachment_url,
            "attributes": {
                "comment": ""
            }
        },
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting the "You must pass a valid document in the body of the request" forever until I stumbled upon [reqbin.com post](https://reqbin.com/req/c-90t7l4bk/curl-patch-request-with-json)

Once I adopted the format to escape all the " (eg \") inside the curl -d argument, things were happy.  I have noticed others seem to have luck using single quotes to encompass all of the -d argument (and ignore the " inside), but I cannot get that to work.  I have also seen """ used all over the place but to me \" is cleaner/more readable.